# retrieve fact info based on variable in puppet

Tags: linux, puppet

I have these facts:

```
"interfaces": "enp1s0f0,enp1s0f1,enp8s0,enp9s0,lo",
"ipaddress": "10.Z.Y.X",
"ipaddress_enp8s0": "10.Z.Y.X",
"ipaddress_lo": "127.0.0.1",
"main_ip": "10.Z.Y.X",
```

So with the main_ip fact I need to retrieve the interface that host it.

I have try the following to compare the ip:

```
  split($::interfaces, ',').each |  String $value | {
   notify { "ipaddress_${value}"  : }
  }
```

but I cannot retrieve the value of the fact with the variable i'm giving...
Can you please advice me how to find the value of the fact with the variable information in puppet?

Or if you have any best idea on how to achieve the main goal it would be appreciated.

Comment: It works fine on Puppet 6. What versions are you using? Any more info?

Comment: This does look like it should work, but `interfaces` does need to be accessed as a fact and not a top scope var to avoid issues.

Comment: I think i was not clear, I need to bring back the interface value, not the name...
Ex: Notify should bring "10.Z.Y.X" but instead is bringing  "ipaddress_enp8s0"

Comment: So the code i'm looking is something like ` notify { facts[ipaddress_${value}]   : }
` but in a way it works in puppet ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any reasonably recent Puppet, you can access node facts through [the `$facts` hash](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.0/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html#the-factsfactname-hash).  This goes back at least to Puppet 4 (latest is Puppet 6).  I don't recall whether it was available in Puppet 3.  In a version that supports it, you should be able to do almost what you described in comments:

```
notify { $facts["ipaddress_${value}"] : }
```

(Note punctuation differences.)

Going back at least as far as Puppet 3, you can also do it with the Puppet Swiss army knife: ERB templates.  Here, the the `scope` object provided automatically to templates is key.

```
$myfact = inline_template('<%= scope.lookupvar("ipaddress_#{@value}") %>')
notify { $myfact : }
```

Comment: Hi,In running this script :
` split($::interfaces, ',').each |  String $value | {`
`   notify { "${value}"  : }`
`   notify { $facts["ipaddress_${value}"] : }`
`}`
But this is the result:

`Error: Evaluation Error: Missing title. The title expression resulted in undef at`

Comment: @josseossa, make sure that you in fact do have an `ipaddress_foo` fact corresponding to *every* interface listed in `$interfaces`.  In support of that, consider omitting the second `notify` to verify that your expectation of the interface list is what Puppet actually sees.  Also, what version of Puppet is this running on?

Comment: I'm running version 4.10

Comment: In the off chance you haven't dissected the error message, iterating over the list is working fine, but at least one of your interfaces is missing an ip address: the second notify is evaluated as `notify { :}`. Like @JohnBollinger suggested, limit your notify resources to the first. Or you could try something like `notify { "Interface ${value} has address ${facts['ipaddress_${value}']}": }` ... that looks like a bit of a mess, but I think you'll get the idea.